# S3 default SSE with KMS still requires a parameter for aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I've created an S3 bucket and configured default SSE to use KMS.

I can upload a file to the bucket with `aws-cli` provided I pass the `--sse aws:kms` flag, e.g.:

`aws s3 cp --sse aws:kms test.txt s3://my-bucket`

But I expect this to work without the `--sse aws:kms` flag since this is default encryption, i.e. it should be applied when no encryption header is specified.

When I try without the header it fails:

`aws s3 cp test.txt s3://my-bucket`


`upload failed: ./test.txt to s3://my-bucket/test.txt An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

If I change from using AWS KMS to S3-managed SSE it works without any `--sse` flag, but I need to use AWS KMS. I've tried adding the following policy to my IAM user making the request but it still fails:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:1111112222:key/aaaabbbb-1122-2222-4444-eeeeff3333"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

What am I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This is only true because your KMS key policy did not specify that the user/role you used to perform the upload could execute GenerateDataKey, Encrypt, and Decrypt against the key.

Add that to your key policy (list yourself as a key user) and it should work.